# How to remove unwanted decimal points from a calculated value using FLOW?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow

I have a Flow Setup that runs when an item is added and performs the approvals accordingly. Part of the flow, I am sending an email to the manager as a confirmation and in the body, I am including a calculated field value which to max has only one decimal point. This field has values like 0,0.5,2.5 etc.

When the email is received these values appear as 0.500000000000, 2.500000000. Is there a work around for this in Flow to fix? Also in addition to this, I am also including a date field displaying date value in the email body. 2018-10-12 appears as: 2018-10-12T07:00:00Z in the email received through flow. Is there a way to fix this as well? Please help, thanks in advance.